# Update model from inside of another controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to push a new row of data to a table, after submitting the form. However, the table, which is called `UrlListCtrl` is different from the form, which is `UrlFormCtrl.`

```
  function UrlFormCtrl($scope, $timeout, UrlService) {
    $scope.message = '';
    var token = '';
    $scope.submitUrl = function(formUrls) {
      console.log('Submitting url', formUrls);
      if (formUrls !== undefined) {
        UrlService.addUrl(formUrls).then(function(response){
          $scope.message = 'Created!';
          // I need to update the view from here
        });
      } else {
        $scope.message = 'The fields were empty!';
      }
    }
```

In `UrlFormCtrl`, I am sending an array to the database to be stored, afterwards I'd like to update the view, where `UrlListCtrl` handles it.

```
  function UrlListCtrl($scope, $timeout, UrlService){
    UrlService.getUrls().then(function(response){
      $scope.urls = response.data;
    });
  }
```

I am trying to push the new data to `$scope.url`. Here is the service:

```
  function UrlService($http) {

    return {
      addUrl: addUrl,
      getUrls: getUrls
    }

    function addUrl(formUrls) {
      console.log('adding url...');
      return $http.post('urls/create', {
        original_url: formUrls.originalUrl,
        redirect_url: formUrls.redirectUrl
      });
    }

    function getUrls() {
      return $http.get('urls/get');
    }


  }
```

I'm still trying to understand Angular, so this is pretty complicated for me. How can I update `$scope.urls` from within `UrlFormCtrl`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure that I understand your question completely but I will try to answer it anyways =).

So you are trying to update a variable whose value was changed in another controller?

That is where `service` can be useful.

Here are the basic steps:

In the service, you have that variable:

```
myApp.service('ServiceName', ['$http', function(){
   var urls = [];

   return{
       urls: urls
   }
}])
```

Put `$watch` in one controller, where you want to get that new value:

```
myApp.controller('FirstController', function(...){

    $scope.$watch(function () {
        return ServiceName.urls;
    }, function (newVal) {
        $scope.urls = newVal;
    });

})
```

Then, you change it from another controller:

```
myApp.controller('SecondController', function(...){

    ServiceName.urls.push('newValue');

})
```

This should do it. `$scope.urls` will be updated in the first controller even if it was changed in the second.

The concept of `$watch` may be new to you. So it basically executes a callback function, whenever the first function returns a new value. That is, whenever the variable that is being watched changes.

**In your case:**

You will have a variable inside your service:

```
function UrlService($http) {

    var urls = [];

    function addUrl(formUrls) {
      console.log('adding url...');
      return $http.post('urls/create', {
        original_url: formUrls.originalUrl,
        redirect_url: formUrls.redirectUrl
      });
    }

    function getUrls() {
      return $http.get('urls/get');
    }

    return {
      addUrl: addUrl,
      getUrls: getUrls
      urls: urls
    }
}
```

Put a `$watch` inside `UrlListCtrl`:

```
function UrlListCtrl($scope, $timeout, UrlService){
    $scope.$watch(function () {
        return UrlService.urls;
    }, function (newVal) {
        $scope.urls = newVal;
    });
}
```

Then, change the value of `urls` from `UrlFormCtrl`:

```
$scope.submitUrl = function(formUrls) {
  if (formUrls !== undefined) {
    UrlService.addUrl(formUrls).then(function(response){
      $scope.message = 'Created!';
      UrlService.urls = response['urls']; 
    });
  } else {
    $scope.message = 'The fields were empty!';
  }
}
```

The `$watch` you put inside `UrlListCtrl` will insure that the new value will be assigned to `$scope.urls` inside `UrlFormCtrl`.